# Google chrome API to get the page that linked to the page on my current tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to get the URL of the page that linked to the page on my current tab using any of the Chrome APIs? For example if I search for "recursion" on google, and click on the first result, is there a way for a chrome extension to know the page that linked to the current page I'm on, (in this example www.google.com)?

Comment: Assuming the result is opened in the same tab, there is no special API so you can use the standard `document.referrer` inside the content script but of course it may be absent.

Comment: What if the result was opened in a new tab?

Comment: Then you can use chrome.tabs.get on the new tab (or chrome.tabs.query for all tabs) and check [openerTabId](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab).